# How to tell if an option is expensive

Tags: options

How to tell as a rough estimate if an option is expensive or not? For stocks, you can compare P/E multiples with similar stocks to estimate whether a stock is expensive w.r.t its sector.

But with an option, how to estimate if an option is expensive? Do we calculate the theoretical price using BSM model using some guess of  IV and compare the theoretical price with the market ask price of the option? Is there a better way?

Comment: This may be a better question for the quantitative finance exchange.

Answer (score 1):

An option, by definition, is a guess about the future value of the stock. If you guess too aggressively, you lose the purchase price of the option; if you guess too conservatively, you may not take the option or may not gain as much as you might have. You need to figure out what you expect to happen, and how confident you are about it, against the cost of taking the option -- and be reasonably confident that the change in the stock's value will be at least large enough to cover the cost of buying into the game.

Opinion: Unless you're comfortable with expectation values and bell curves around them, it's significantly easier to lose money on options than to profit on them. And I'm not convinced that even statisticians can really do this well. I've always been told that the best use for options is hedging an investment you've already made; treating them as your primary bet is gambling, not investment.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to compare the implied volatility with the realised volatility over a period similar to the time left to expiry. However there are plenty of reasons why the implied may be higher than the historical, for example because the market volatility has increased overall or because the underlying company is going to report their results before the option expires.